# Build Android apps server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, printing, driver, appserver

I'm building an Android app for printing documents by the application server that will send the document to the server and the server sends the document to the selected printer to print (on the server I want to install the printer drivers), I am currently in the planning stage which server crowned used for such a task?

Comment: You mean, you want an off-the-shelf printer server that you can send documents to from your android device? What makes you think such a thing exists?

Comment: I want to set up a remote server to send a print job to the printer after sending server the document from my Android device

Comment: Then you need to select the tools to build the server with, build the server, and send the documents.